# Don't allow client to make Angular DOM changes

Tags: angular, dom, google-chrome-devtools, dom-manipulation, angular-changedetection

I have an Angular application. Right now, I can edit the elements by inspecting on chrome and can make the changes like removing disabled property and so on (I know [attr.disabled] is there but this is just an example). I have to achieve the functionality that the user should not make any changes on DOM and if he can, then it should not make any impact on my form or my application.

I have checked [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), is it the only way or there is any other solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a futile attempt, I can almost see the future question in SO "How do I write a user script that prevents creation of MutationObservers" :)

Comment: So there is no other option to prevent this?

Comment: Client is client, the owner has full control, you can only make it harder on them, but you can't prevent it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you suggest any solution to make it harder?